# BTRFS on RHEL8 - compiling kernel module or making userspace tools work

Tags: redhat, linux-kernel, btrfs, kernel-modules, rhel8

### Context

I recently installed RHEL 8 without realizing that it [no longer supports BTRFS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/file-systems-and-storage_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8#btrfs-has-been-removed_file-systems-and-storage).

Unfortunately, I have 4 disks in BTRFS RAID10. I don't have enough space on my other disks to hold the data present on the BTRFS disks, so copying it all elsewhere while booted from a USB drive is out the window.

I have my initial question, then some followup questions regarding the approaches I took that failed. Feel free to just focus on the "how to get BTRFS working" part of this problem, although I am curious to learn about the other issues if you have answers to any part of this.

### Question 1

1. Is there a (relatively) easy way to get BTRFS working on RHEL8?

### Userspace btrfs-progs

My first attempt to make this work was to compile and install `btrfs-progs` with the following:

```sh
# Install deps
sudo dnf install libuuid-devel libblkid-devel lzo-devel zlib-devel libzstd-devel e2fsprogs-devel e2fsprogs-libs e2fsprogs libgcrypt-devel libsodium-devel libattr-devel
# Install deps for doc gen
sudo dnf install asciidoc xmlto source-highlight

# Shallow-clone latest release
git clone --depth 1 --branch v5.14.1 https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs.git
cd btrfs-progs
git switch -c v5.14.1

# Build
#   --disable-zoned since that feature needs kernel >=5.10
export CFLAGS="-O3 -pipe -frecord-gcc-switches -mtune=native -march=native"
export CPPFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export SODIUM_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export ZSTD_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export ZLIB_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export UUID_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export PYTHON_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS

./autogen.sh
./configure --with-crypto=libsodium --disable-zoned
make -j12
sudo make install
```

It seems to install correctly and is accessible to my user:

```
$ which btrfs
/usr/local/bin/btrfs

$ ls -1 /usr/local/bin/ | grep btrfs
btrfs
btrfsck
btrfs-convert
btrfs-find-root
btrfs-image
btrfs-map-logical
btrfs-select-super
btrfstune
fsck.btrfs
mkfs.btrfs

$ btrfs version
btrfs-progs v5.14.1
```

However, root apparently doesn't have `/usr/local/bin` in its path by default. I added `export PATH+=":/usr/local/bin" to` /etc/profile`and`/root/.bash_profile`, but neither of them seem to get sourced automatically when using` sudo`or when dropping into a root shell with`sudo su`.

When specifying the full path to the binary, it complains it can't open `/dev/btrfs-control`. Querying my local search engine, some suggest needing udev, but that's already installed (maybe misconfigured?)

```
$ sudo btrfs version
sudo: btrfs: command not found

$ sudo /usr/local/bin/btrfs device scan
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
WARNING: failed to open /dev/btrfs-control, skipping device registration: No such file or directory
WARNING: failed to open /dev/btrfs-control, skipping device registration: No such file or directory
WARNING: failed to open /dev/btrfs-control, skipping device registration: No such file or directory
WARNING: failed to open /dev/btrfs-control, skipping device registration: No such file or directory
ERROR: there were 4 errors while registering devices
```

Other BTRFS commands seem to work:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/btrfs filesystem show /dev/sda
Label: 'wdred'  uuid: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeee
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 2.13TiB
    devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 1.07TiB path /dev/sda
    devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 1.07TiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    3 size 5.46TiB used 1.07TiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    4 size 5.46TiB used 1.07TiB path /dev/sdd
```

However, I've been afraid to mount the partitions or perform any operations on them given the above error, for fear that its missing components that would cause it to mangle my data.

### Questions 2, 3, 4

2. Is it safe to attempt to use btrfs to mount the disks given the above errors?
3. What's up with the `/dev/btrfs-control` error on `btrfs device scan`?
4. How can I get `sudo` and `sudo su` to have `/usr/local/bin` in its path by default?

### BTRFS kernel module

I wondered if it might be better to compile a kernel module, but having almost no kernel hacking experience, it went badly.

It seems like I need to set `CONFIG_BTRFS_FS=m` in my kernel config to start. It's not there currently, and I seemed to remember being able to do this in `menuconfig`.

```
$ grep "BTRFS" /boot/config-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 
# CONFIG_BTRFS_FS is not set
```

The RHEL documentation mentions how to load kernel modules and such, but not about how to build them. I consulted archwiki, and tried to download the RHEL8 kernel from the Red Hat site. The download page for RHEL8 had a "Sources" tab with a 20G .iso file. I downloaded it, mounted it, and found it was stuffed with .rpm files and didn't look anything like the linux kernel source repo. I was a little lost.

I then went to `/usr/src/kernels/`, initialized a git repo out of fear I would clobber something important, and went on trying to figure out how to build the kernel module or change things in menuconfig.

```
$ cd /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64
$ sudo su
# git init
# git add -A
# git commit -m "Unmodified kernel"

# make mrproper
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/bin2c
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
arch/x86/Makefile:184: *** Compiler lacks asm-goto support..  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1361: _clean_arch/x86] Error 2
```

Lacking asm-goto support, the internet suggested that I may need `elfutils-libelf-devel` but I appeared to already have that.

For funzies I tried building it with `clang` and with `gcc-toolset-10`, but both of those had the same error.

### Question 5

- Any ideas why `Compiler lacks asm-goto support`?
- What's a good resource on how to build kernel modules / patch kernels / modify your system's kernel?

### System info

```
$ uname -a
Linux rhel 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 7 07:07:31 EDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)


$ scl run gcc-toolset-10 'gcc --version'
gcc (GCC) 10.2.1 20201112 (Red Hat 10.2.1-8)

$ clang --version
clang version 11.0.0 (Red Hat 11.0.0-1.module+el8.4.0+8598+a071fcd5)
```

---

Thanks for reading this far! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Supposedly CONFIG_BTRFS is enabled in ELrepo kernel-ml kernels. You also need the userspace stuff, which is in elrepo-testing (and has been since RHEL 8 was in beta). This should allow you to recover your files so you can switch to another filesystem.

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks @MichaelHampton !

Comment: The other possibility is to enable Oracle Linux repos and install so callwd  unbreakable kernel

Comment: @kofemann is there any reason to use the Oracle UEK over the mainline linux kernel for this?

Comment: The `/etc/profile` should be loaded if you switch to root with `sudo -i` or `su -` `pam_env` is probably what you want to use to edit PATH, which likely sets up the env based on `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, @MichaelHampton's answer worked.

I added [`kernel-ml`](https://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml) from [ELrepo](https://elrepo.org/tiki/HomePage) like this:

```sh
sudo rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
sudo yum install https://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-8.el8.elrepo.noarch.rpm
sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
```

Note that I already built the userspace tools `btrfs-progs` and outlined the build steps in the question above. If you're coming here from Google, you'll need to install `btrfs-progs` in addition to the kernel module.

Then restarted, checked that I was running the mainline kernel, and was able to mount my disks with BTRFS and read their data.

```
$ sudo reboot

$ uname -a
Linux rhel 5.14.8-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Sep 25 10:32:52 EDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo mount UUID=zzz -o defaults,noatime /mnt/hdd

$ ls /mnt/hdd
all my files :)
```